# How do I properly annotate the content of an article/blog post preview for accessibility and SEO?

Tags: html, semantic-markup, wai-aria

It's pretty common to want to have article and blog post previews, and you see it in several places, including news sites, personal blog sites, and such. There are a variety of things you may want to display as part of that preview:

- Article title
- Date it was published
- How long it might take to read
- Various categorical tags
- A short summary of the article
- A short preview snippet from the beginning of the post

The first four are pretty obvious on how you should annotate them:

- Article and blog post titles should use `<h1>`-`<h6>` if at all possible/practical, and if they can't, they should be marked with ARIA `role="heading"`. Screen readers and search engines both understand how to interpret both variants.
- The date it was published should use `<time>` where possible, marked with a `datetime` set to a date to both help screen readers (like [JAWS](https://lab.dotjay.com/tests/screen-readers/date-time/)) and search engine crawlers.
- The reading time estimate should also use `<time>`, but with `datetime` set to a pure duration. This lets search engines read it much more easily.
- Tag lists should just use an unordered list of links to help screen readers properly navigate it. Search engines typically recognize them by other means, so the format is mainly for accessibility.

But the last two aren't so obvious. I know they should probably be treated similarly to one another, but I can't seem to find any recommendations anywhere. My first reaction is to enclose them in `<p>`s, but that feels horribly wrong as they have a fairly common semantic meaning beyond just being a block of text.

What's the proper way to annotate summaries and previews of articles and blog posts specifically for accessibility and SEO? (I'm specifically *not* including stuff like Microdata and JSON-LD, just basic HTML+ARIA stuff.)

Comment: Would a teaser contain a summary *and* a preview snippet, or only one of the two?

Comment: Only one of the two. I left that implied because although I know it would've been obvious you would only want one, they *are* semantically distinct at some level. When I tried drawing that distinction, I found I was either distracting from the real question or conflating the semantic differences, so I just left the mutual exclusivity implied.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have a good handle on semantic html and how that helps screen reader users.  The headings for articles is a great start.  Using a semantic `<article>` tag is good too, although support for navigating directly to an <article> tag is only supported in some screen readers (JAWS and VoiceOver but not NVDA).

If you have a snippet of the article and end with ellipses and a "read more" type link, make sure the "read more" has additional contextual information, such as:

```html
<article>
  <h2 id="articleHeading1">Are flying cars a reality?</h2>
  <p>Flying cars are common in science fiction movies, but do we have the technology to build them today. In an
    interview with Dr Foobar...<a href="#" id="readMore1" aria-labelledby="readMore1 articleHeading1">read more</a>
  </p>
  <ul aria-label="tags">
    <li>science fiction</li>
    <li>cars</li>
  </ul>
</article>
```

The `<time>` element helps some screen readers (VoiceOver will announce it but NVDA won't) but I wouldn't recommend "hiding" information in a <time> element.  For example,

```html
<p>We open presents on <time datetime="2019-12-25 06:00">Christmas</time> early in the morning.</p>
```

VoiceOver will say *"We open presents on Christmas, December 25th, 2019, 6am, early in the morning"* but NVDA will just say *"We open presents on Christmas early in the morning"*.

So some screen reader users will hear the extra date/time info ("6am") but others won't.  And the sighted user won't know about the 6am time either.  If you mirror what is displayed visually with what is specified in the <time> element, then you'd be ok, but then the <time> element won't really buy you anything.

Having your tag list in a `<ul>` is fine.  That's enough semantic information to make sense.  A screen reader user can navigate to list elements using the <kbd>L</kbd> shortcut key.  You don't need a special "these are the tags" description but you can certainly do that.

```html
<ul aria-label="these are the tags">
  <li>alpha</li>
  <li>beta</li>
  <li>gamma</li>
</ul>
```

The time to read an article is exactly what you said, just text.  A `<p>` is fine.  Be aware, though, that having a reading estimate can be stressful to some users.  For cognitive disorders that cause slower reading times, those users might feel "pressure" to read the article in that amount of time.  The estimate is a nice guess on the length of the article, but is subjective to an average reading time.  A preferred approach might be to just state how long the article is, perhaps in number of paragraphs or a rough estimate on how many "pages" it would be if printed using default settings.  So an article that is a "half page" might mean 15 seconds to a screen reader user that has the speech rate set very high, or 3 min to an average reader, or 15 min for reading disorder.

Comment: I'm thinking you might have a point in questioning the use of "estimated reading time" rather than some other similar, but more objective metric that's still better than providing a raw word count.

Comment: I will note that for my particular immediate use case, all my previews are also links to the article themselves, so the "read more" link would be redundant.